# Split database to different SQL Server

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

Sorry for my English.

There is database on SQL Server 2005 Enterprise. I wrote program which splits all tables on fileGroups by datetime. But the problem is that database schema is not designed for it and most information stays on the `PRIMARY` filegroup.

Please tell me how I can spread (split) tables onto two or more database servers for increased performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the syntax on how to move a table from one file group to another? See [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
MOVE TO MyNewFileGroup
```

Comment: I know how to move a table from one file group to another. I am interested in move some tables to another ms sql server.

Comment: Server A, database B, has table C. You want to move table C to Server D? Do all the applications know that this table has moved or do you need something to keep a copy of that table on both servers in synch?

Comment: Could you tell me how to create partition function which take as argument size of table?

Comment: The creation of a partition function isn't really aligned with sizes. You could probably fake it if your table(s) have an auto-increment key on them, then you could define ranges for whatever size you feel appropriate. That said, a partition function isn't going to help you accomplish putting data on a different server. It has a different purpose.

Comment: I do this with date time. CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION Partitions_PFN_{0}(datetime)  AS   RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES ({1}), but it not useful for me. most tables have not auto-increment fields, pk field is binary

Comment: when i try execute ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test]
MOVE TO fg4 it fails to Incorrect syntax near 'MOVE'.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to look into MS SQL Server's partitioning capabilities.  You should not be doing this manually.  Let the database solve that issue for you.

Comment: I just want to know how I can create distributed database